# Python 2.7 tkinter card matching game

Tags: python, tkinter

Ok, so I have to do this project for school and make a matching card game using python 2.7. here is my code.

```
import sys
import Tkinter
import random
from Tkinter import *
#==== Main Window ====#
root=Tk()
root.title('Matching Game')
root.geometry('750x770+400+20')
#===== Load Images =====#
back= PhotoImage(file='images/back.gif')
card1=PhotoImage(file='images/card_front_01.gif')
card2=PhotoImage(file='images/card_front_02.gif')
card3=PhotoImage(file='images/card_front_03.gif')
card4=PhotoImage(file='images/card_front_04.gif')
card5=PhotoImage(file='images/card_front_05.gif')
card6=PhotoImage(file='images/card_front_06.gif')
card7=PhotoImage(file='images/card_front_07.gif')
card8=PhotoImage(file='images/card_front_08.gif')
card9=PhotoImage(file='images/card_front_09.gif')
cards=[card1,card2,card3,card4,card5,card6,card7,card8,card9]
useable=[]
useable.append(cards[random.randrange(0,9)])
useable.append(cards[random.randrange(0,9)])
useable.append(cards[random.randrange(0,9)])
useable.append(cards[random.randrange(0,9)])
useable.append(cards[random.randrange(0,9)])
useable.append(cards[random.randrange(0,9)])

f1=useable[random.randrange(0,6)]
f2=useable[random.randrange(0,6)]
f3=useable[random.randrange(0,6)]
f4=useable[random.randrange(0,6)]
f5=useable[random.randrange(0,6)]
f6=useable[random.randrange(0,6)]
f7=useable[random.randrange(0,6)]
f8=useable[random.randrange(0,6)]
f9=useable[random.randrange(0,6)]
f10=useable[random.randrange(0,6)]
f11=useable[random.randrange(0,6)]
f12=useable[random.randrange(0,6)]
#===========Front=======#
front1=Label(image=f1)
front1.grid(row=1,column=1)
front2=Label(image=f2)
front2.grid(row=1,column=2)
front3=Label(image=f3)
front3.grid(row=1,column=3)
front4=Label(image=f4)
front4.grid(row=1,column=4)
front5=Label(image=f5)
front5.grid(row=2,column=1)
front6=Label(image=f6)
front6.grid(row=2,column=2)
front7=Label(image=f7)
front7.grid(row=2,column=3)
front8=Label(image=f8)
front8.grid(row=2,column=4)
front9=Label(image=f9)
front9.grid(row=3,column=1)
front10=Label(image=f10)
front10.grid(row=3,column=2)
front11=Label(image=f11)
front11.grid(row=3,column=3)
front12=Label(image=f12)
front12.grid(row=3,column=4)


#========Functions======#
def flip(y):
global step,card1,card2
if step==1:
Button.config(image=All[the_cards][y][0])
card1=x
step=2
elif step==2:
Button.config(image=All[the_cards][y][0])
card2=x
step=3
if card[card1][0]==card[card2][0]:
card[card1][1]=1
card[card2][1]=1
step=0







#=======Back======#
button=Button(image=back,command=lambda:flip(1))
button.grid(row=1,column=1)
button=Button(image=back,command=lambda:flip(2))
button.grid(row=1,column=2)
button=Button(image=back,command=lambda:flip(3))
button.grid(row=1,column=3)
button=Button(image=back,command=lambda:flip(4))
button.grid(row=1,column=4)
button=Button(image=back,command=lambda:flip(5))
button.grid(row=2,column=1)
button=Button(image=back,command=lambda:flip(6))
button.grid(row=2,column=2)
button=Button(image=back,command=lambda:flip(7))
button.grid(row=2,column=3)
button=Button(image=back,command=lambda:flip(8))
button.grid(row=2,column=4)
button=Button(image=back,command=lambda:flip(9))
button.grid(row=3,column=1)
button=Button(image=back,command=lambda:flip(10))
button.grid(row=3,column=2)
button=Button(image=back,command=lambda:flip(11))
button.grid(row=3,column=3)
button=Button(image=back,command=lambda:flip(12))
button.grid(row=3,column=4)

#=========Main Program=======#
the_cards=[[0,0]]
All=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
random.shuffle(All)
All=All[0:6]
All=All*2
random.shuffle(All)
for i in range(0,12):
the_cards.append([the_cards[i],0])

card1=100
card2=101
step=1


root.mainloop()
```

my error is "line 106, in flip
    Button.config(image=All[the_cards][y][0])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list"

can someone please tell me why this isn't working and how to fix it? Thanks!!!

Comment: The error is because `All` and `the_cards` are both lists, so the latter can't be used to index the former.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message gives away the problem right away.

Trust in the error message: it is telling you exactly what the problem is. "list indices **must be integers, not list**"

When you do `All[the_cards]`, ask yourself "what is `the_cards`?"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in place of

```
All[ the_cards ][y][0]
```

you should use

```
All[ the_cards[y] ][0]
```

or

```
All[ the_cards[y][0] ]
```

But I didn't test it.